# Hibernate @OneToOne Unidirectional Mapping...Cascade Delete

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, one-to-one

I'm working on a Spring Boot Application with Hibernate and I'm just trying to understand the correct way to approach a OneToOne mapping when it comes to using cascade delete.

So, we have a User table and a PasswordResetToken table. A user has standard user columns: id, username, password, email.

A password reset token has an id, a FK to userId, and a string for a token.

So, my question now is: how do I correctly model this so we can properly cascade delete?

My thought process is that we have a unidirectional mapping since password reset token has a FK to user, and user does NOT have a FK to password reset token.

So I would think that we would place the @OneToOne on our PasswordResetToken class in Java and not have a reference to PasswordResetToken in our User class, but then the PasswordResetToken class will have a reference to a User object.

But, through some stackoverflowing, I found that people would have the child object (PasswordResetToken) inside the parent object (User) despite the parent object's table not having a reference to the child object's table (since the User table doesn't have a PasswordResetToken in it) which allows for adding the cascade remove to the @OneToOne annotation which means that when a User gets deleted, all children will get deleted as well.

So, which way is the right way to model this relationship?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to solve your problem. Some are less, some are more efficient.

#### Bidirectional with foreign key

```java
@Entity
public class PasswordResetToken {
 
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User User;
 
    // other fields
}

@Entity
public class User {

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
              fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private PasswordResetToken passwordResetToken;

    // other fields
}
```

#### Bidirectional with principal/parent's primary key as foreign key

Since it's 1-1 relationship, you could use `User`'s ID as a primary key for `PasswordResetToken` table.

```java
@Entity
public class PasswordResetToken {
 
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId
    private User User;
 
    // other fields
}

@Entity
public class User {

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
              fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private PasswordResetToken passwordResetToken;

    // other fields
}
```

#### Unidirectional

If you want to have unidirectional mapping, and to have `PasswordResetToken` entity as part of `User` entity, you'll have to move the foreign key to `User` table, since `@JoinColumn` has to be applied on entity owning the foreign key.

```java
@Entity
public class User {

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
              fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn("password_reset_token_id") // FK in User table
    private PasswordResetToken passwordResetToken;

    // other fields
}
```

---

As for performance, the most efficient is bidirectional with `@MapsId`. Bidirectional with `@JoinColumn` is less efficient, and I'm not sure about unidirectional mapping. One to one mappings are not that common in practice, and I'm not sure how often people use unidirectional mapping. Probably not at all, since the foreign key is usually on dependent side.

Comment: Thank you, I'm currently doing the Unidirectional approach, since I've heard bidirectional can be inefficient. But, I'm confused because, in my User table, I don't have a reference to a passwordResetToken object. But in my Java class, we create a reference to it?
I'm a little confused on that, should I not be comparing the two?

Comment: Actually, bidirectional mappings are more efficient. You can use [this image](https://vladmihalcea.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/relationships.png) from [this post](https://vladmihalcea.com/14-high-performance-java-persistence-tips/) as a reference guide. Also you should not compare DB model with object model (ORM is there to overcome these differences). Even though you don't have a FK in User table, you can tell Hibernate how to create object that you need. For example, in bidirectional mapping you have `@JoinColumn` in entity which has FK and then use `mappedBy` in other entity.

Comment: Also, it depends on the data you have. If you have a one-to-many relationship between Post and Comment (for example) and you want to fetch a Post with 10000 Comments, then the bidirectional mapping would be less efficient as it needs to fetch too much data from the DB and store it in objects. When using HIbernate (or any other ORM) you should always think about the amount of data you'll be dealing with and adjust your mappings accordingly.

Comment: Ah, yeah I was hung up on comparing the DB model and the object model. I'll separate them next time! And yeah, so it's dependent on your data. Thank you for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how big the token is, but what is wrong with storing the token in the `User` entity as simple column? You can abstract some parts by using an `@Embeddable` but really this should IMO be in the same table. If you are concerned with the amount of data fetched, you should be using DTOs to reduce the amount of data.

Comment: I suppose I could, but I wanted to separate tables as much as possible just for learning purposes.